# SQL query for Pligg CMS select all published news only from one category

Tags: php, mysql, pligg

Hello everyone I am new in PHP and MySQL but I need a simple (probably) sql query that will select all published link from one category (for example sport with ID number 6)

Now I have a query that selects all published news from all categories

```
<ul>
    {php}
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * from ' . table_links . ' WHERE link_status = "published" ORDER BY link_published_date DESC LIMIT 5');
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        printf("<li>%s voturi | <a href='".$this->_vars['my_pligg_base']."/story.php?id=%s'><span style='font-weight:bold'>%s</span></a></li>", $row["link_votes"], $row["link_id"], $row["link_title"]);
    }
    {/php}
</ul>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found the correct query, thanks!

```
<ul>
    {php}
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * from ' . table_links . ' WHERE link_status = "published"  and link_category = 1 ORDER BY link_published_date DESC LIMIT 5');
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        printf("<li>%s voturi | <a href='".$this->_vars['my_pligg_base']."/story.php?id=%s'><span style='font-weight:bold'>%s</span></a></li>", $row["link_votes"], $row["link_id"], $row["link_title"]);
    }
    {/php}
</ul>
```